# Rails stuck on migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made a mistake.  I created a scaffold for `usershorcut`.  I meant to use `usershortcut` with a `t`.

I then created a migration to rename the table.  And I used a find/substitute in my Rails editor.

I must have changed something that I shouldn't have after I ran the rake on development.

Because when I run the rake on Heroku, I get

```
uninitialized constant CreateUsershorcuts
```

But, my Rails migration is now:

```
20140421133729_create_usershortcuts.rb
```

With:

```
class Createusershortcuts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :usershortcuts do |t|
     t.integer :user_id
     t.string :shortcut_name
     t.text :shortcut_url

     t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I don't know what to change to get past this rake error.

Can I delete a migration and add a new one?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails expects `20140421133729_create_usershortcuts.rb` to contain `CreateUsershortcuts` whereas it actually contains `Createusershortcuts`.

You could either change the migration or the name of the class inside it - as long as they match it shouldn't matter what you do